# Need to Restore Desktop Files - Accidentally Deleted Desktop Directory Using Git Bash

Tags: bash, git, github, repository, restore

I am new to Git and I did something silly.

I forked a repository from GitHub, then cloned it onto my computer using Git Bash. Long story short, I wanted the directory to be on my desktop but for some reason, I used `rm -r Desktop` and now all of my desktop files are gone.

I then cloned the repo to my Desktop and it's the only thing I have on there. I tried closing Git Bash since I did not commit any changes but my files are still gone and I am unsure of what to do.

How can I recover my Desktop files? I did not commit or push or do anything of that nature so I'd assume the changes are still local. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: In dark times, I often turn to https://ohshitgit.com/, although from your description I suspect you may be in a bit of a pickle

Comment: Well, if you do not have backups, the only thing to do is stop using this computer immediately and shut it down. Every single new disk operation can overwrite some of your precious data. So stop now. Then, try to recover whatever you can and has not been yet overwritten, with appropriate recovery tools. Of course, to do so, you'll have to boot your computer from a different file system than your hard disk drive (USB key, external drive...) else you will continue overwriting your precious files.

Answer (score 0):

TestDisk is a tool for recovering files which have been deleted.

1. Install testdisk
2. nter `testisk` into the command line, and the utility will start.
3. Select your partition to search in.
4. Select quick search or deeper search.
5. testdisk will output which files have been recovered and then you can decide to recover or not.

A tutorial on testdisk at the following link,
https://www.journaldev.com/36700/how-to-install-testdisk-on-linux-and-recover-deleted-files